# Calculated properties for each element in array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a use case where my data store has an array of products, each with a price and quantity.

What I would like to do is calculate the 'total' for each product (price x quantity). I can do so by created a new computed property which re-calculates the entire array, appending a new property with the total.

The issue is, this requires recalculating every item in the array every time a single item changes.

I could use a component to calculate and display, but I also need to calculate a total (which is the sum of all computed prices on each product).

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
[
  {
    "Product ID": 1,
    "Price": 10,
    "Quantity": 5,
    "Calculated Total": 50
  },
  {
    "Product ID": 2,
    "Price": 12,
    "Quantity": 10,
    "Calculated Total": 120
  }
]
```

Comment: Depending on how you use the calculated value, you might just use a method. The calculation of the grand total is going to require similar computing to calculating the computed array, so it's probably a non-issue, and you can just use the computed array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a computed value to map through the original array and sum the values. e.g say the original array is named originalArray, do:

```js
 computed: {
   computedTotal() {
      let sum = 0
      originalArray.map(item => sum += item["Calculated Total"])
      return sum
  }
}
```